# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error code in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm creating a simple note taking iOS app with Swift.

When I attempt to save the location of the device to the note object I get an error of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`. I understand that this error is related to the deallocation of memory during run time, but I cant find the issue. I'm using very similar code to perform the same operation elsewhere in the app with success.

I have tried to enable Zombie object with no luck. I have also looked at a number of questions on here plus blog posts, but they did not help me find the issue (but did help me to understand it).

This is the code that the error is thrown in. I have also added the entire (non refactored) class to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0JEzuXSN) incase more context is needed.

```
    var audioNote: AudioNote!
    func createAudioNote() {
        let appDelegate: AppDelegate  = localAppDelegate()
        let managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let entityDescription:NSEntityDescription! = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AudioNote", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        audioNote = AudioNote(entity: entityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        audioNote.date_created = NSDate()
        audioNote.url = "\(soundFileURL)"

        if (appDelegate.userLocation != nil){
            println(appDelegate.userLocation!.coordinate.latitude)// <- Contains latitude as expected
            println(audioNote)// <- Contains note as expected
            audioNote.latitude = appDelegate.userLocation!.coordinate.latitude // <- Error throws here
            audioNote.longitude = appDelegate.userLocation!.coordinate.longitude
        }
    }
```

The stack trace points me towards and issue with CoreData, but beyond checking the naming of the entity and attributes I'm not sure what to do.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
    * thread #1: tid = 0x581ddd, 0x0000000112ef1017 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x0000000112ef1017 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23
    frame #1: 0x0000000111d751f5 CoreData`_PFManagedObject_coerceValueForKeyWithDescription + 1493
    frame #2: 0x0000000111d4e2f1 CoreData`_sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 177
    * frame #3: 0x0000000110087c79 ELLIE`ELLIE.AudioNoteController.createAudioNote (self=<unavailable>)() -> () + 2345 at AudioNoteController.swift:117
    frame #4: 0x000000011008601b ELLIE`ELLIE.AudioNoteController.saveAudioNote (sender=AnyObject at 0x00007fff4fc050e8, self=<unavailable>)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 59 at AudioNoteController.swift:47
    frame #5: 0x0000000110086076 ELLIE`@objc ELLIE.AudioNoteController.saveAudioNote (ELLIE.AudioNoteController)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 54 at AudioNoteController.swift:0
    frame #6: 0x0000000110a36d62 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    frame #7: 0x0000000110b4850a UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    frame #8: 0x0000000110b478d9 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    frame #9: 0x0000000110a83958 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    frame #10: 0x0000000110a84282 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
    frame #11: 0x0000000110a4a541 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    frame #12: 0x0000000110a57cdc UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
    frame #13: 0x0000000110a3259c UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    frame #14: 0x00000001124c3431 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #15: 0x00000001124b92fd CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    frame #16: 0x00000001124b8934 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 868
    frame #17: 0x00000001124b8366 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #18: 0x0000000115c8ea3e GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #19: 0x0000000110a358c0 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
    frame #20: 0x0000000110097237 ELLIE`main + 135 at AppDelegate.swift:16
    frame #21: 0x0000000113628145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #22: 0x0000000113628145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you've declared your custom `NSManagedObject` sub-class in your Model schema. This will need to be in the fully qualified `APP.ClassName` format, e.g:

[image: Class declared in Model editor]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it will help, but I'd recommend to rewrite this part:

```
if (appDelegate.userLocation != nil){
    println(appDelegate.userLocation!.coordinate.latitude)// <- Contains latitude as expected
    println(audioNote)// <- Contains note as expected
    audioNote.latitude = appDelegate.userLocation!.coordinate.latitude // <- Error throws here
    audioNote.longitude = appDelegate.userLocation!.coordinate.longitude
 }
```

Like that:

```
if let location = appDelegate.userLocation{
     print(audioNote)
     audioNote.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
     audioNote.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
}
```

Comment: Still crashes on latitude assign?

Comment: Yup, still crashes on the equivalent line.